# Unity GetComponent not searching other objects

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

To be honest based on the documentation I cannot tell but should `GetComponent<T>()` search all objects in the scene for the component? I have a pub/sub setup and have various EmptyObjects in a scene named `<name>Publisher` ie `WorldPublisher` \ `PlayerPublisher` where I can attach various needed publishers.

My idea was that I could call `GetComponent<KeyBindingPublisher>()` and that would give back that script. However, I am getting a null so it cannot seem to find it from say the player GameObject.

I do not want to attach both pub/sub to the player GameObject that feels too tightly coupled.

I am currently doing this:

```
GameObject playerEvents = GameObject.Find("PlayerPublishers");
KeyBindingPublisher keyBindingPublisher = playerEvents.GetComponent<KeyBindingPublisher>();
```

Which does appear to work but that seems to tightly couple the subscriber script and UI which I was trying to avoid. I might not need to put a `PlayerPublishers` object so just want to be able to get a ref to the script without knowing all the objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call [`GameObject.GetComponent`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponent.html), that will search for a matching component attached to the specific GameObject that you call it on. If you want to include other GameObjects in the search, you have a few options:

- [`GameObject.GetComponentInChildren`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponentInChildren.html) will search that GameObject and all of its children.
- [`GameObject.GetComponentInParent`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponentInParent.html) will search that GameObject and all of its parents.
- [`Object.FindObjectOfType`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.FindObjectOfType.html) will search all loaded Unity objects.

If you are searching for multiple objects, there are similar functions that return arrays of matches.

As you might imagine, casting a wide net can have an impact on performance. Searching the entire scene is ideally something that should be kept to a minimum.

If you are looking for exactly one instance of a `KeyBindingPublisher` that other scripts can reference across all scenes, you might look into a design pattern called a singleton. [Here is an example from GameDev Stack Exchange](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/116009/in-unity-how-do-i-correctly-implement-the-singleton-pattern) that includes some code samples for achieving this in Unity3D.

Comment: This answer already mentions many options .. so just wanted to throw **dependency injection** like e.g. using [Zenject aka Extenject](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/utilities/extenject-dependency-injection-ioc-157735) in as well ;)

Comment: This is great still working my way through unity GameObject hierarchy. GetComponentInParent is what I would like to use keeps me from need to know where something is attached. I was actually going down the singleton rabbit hole last night.